# Findout overlapped text

Tags: c#, itext

I want to highlight overlapped text from PDF. Got all words coordinates using "PDFExchangeviewer.exe" and then converted to dot.net rectangle. In dotnet rectangle found intersection of rectangle and highlighted the intersected words using itextsharp. But it highlighting unwanted words in PDF rather than overlapped text. Please post solution to this. Below shown is my part of the code in c#

```
foreach (var pdfrect in WordpageCoordinates)
{
    float X = (float)pdfrect.Item1;
    float Y = reader.GetPageSize(pdfPg).Top - (float)pdfrect.Item4;
    float Width = (float)pdfrect.Item3 - X;
    float Height = (float)(pdfrect.Item4) - (float)(pdfrect.Item2);

    DotNetRect.Add(new System.Drawing.RectangleF(X, Y, Width, Height));
}
for(int j = 0; j < DotNetRect.Count; j++)
{
    System.Drawing.RectangleF MasterRect = DotNetRect[j];
    System.Drawing.RectangleF ChildRect = new System.Drawing.RectangleF();

    if (j == DotNetRect.Count - 1)
    {
        break;
    }
    for (int k = j + 1; k < DotNetRect.Count; k++)
    {
        ChildRect = DotNetRect[k];

        System.Drawing.RectangleF NewRect = new System.Drawing.RectangleF(ChildRect.X, ChildRect.Y , ChildRect.Width, ChildRect.Height);

        if (MasterRect.IntersectsWith(NewRect))
        {                           
            {
                iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Annotrect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle((float)WordpageCoordinates[k].Item1, (float)WordpageCoordinates[k].Item2, (float)WordpageCoordinates[k].Item3, (float)WordpageCoordinates[k].Item4);
                //iTextSharp.text.Rectangle Annotrect = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle((float)ClsGlobal.TextCoordinatesList[k].Item1, (float)ClsGlobal.TextCoordinatesList[k].Item2, (float)ClsGlobal.TextCoordinatesList[k].Item3, (float)ClsGlobal.TextCoordinatesList[k].Item4);
                //float[] quad = { Annotrect.Left, Annotrect.Bottom, Annotrect.Right, Annotrect.Bottom, Annotrect.Left, Annotrect.Top, Annotrect.Right, Annotrect.Top };
                float[] quad = { Annotrect.Left, Annotrect.Top, Annotrect.Right, Annotrect.Top, Annotrect.Left, Annotrect.Bottom, Annotrect.Right, Annotrect.Bottom };
                PdfAnnotation HighlightAnnotation = PdfAnnotation.CreateMarkup(pdfstamper.Writer, Annotrect, "Text Overlap", PdfAnnotation.MARKUP_HIGHLIGHT, quad);
                HighlightAnnotation.Title = "Overlap Text Highlighter\n" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString();
                HighlightAnnotation.Color = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.GREEN;
                pdfstamper.AddAnnotation(HighlightAnnotation, pdfPg);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are testing whether 2 Rectangles intersect, but you are not working with the intersection. Take the intersection for the annotation. The intersection is the overlapping part.

```
RectangleF intersection = RectangleF.Intersect(MasterRect, NewRect);
```

With this static method [`RectangleF.Intersect Method (RectangleF, RectangleF)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h8hdx977(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static RectangleF Intersect(
    RectangleF a,
    RectangleF b
)
```

There is no need to create a copy of `ChildRect`. `IntersectsWith` only tests for an intersection but does not create one and does not change the rectangle. Since `RectangleF` is a struct and therefore a value type, a copy of it is passed to the method anyway. If it was a class, i.e. a reference type, the method could theoretically change its fields and properties.

`Intersect` returns an empty rectangle if there is no intersection. Therefore, you could also first create the intersection and then test if it is not empty instead of using `IntersectsWith`.

```
RectangleF intersection = RectangleF.Intersect(MasterRect, ChildRect);
if (!intersection.IsEmpty)
{
    // create the annotation with `intersection`
}
```

---

Instead of writing

```
if (j == DotNetRect.Count - 1)
{
    break;
}
```

change the loop condition to (added `- 1`):

```
for(int j = 0; j < DotNetRect.Count - 1; j++)
```

Comment: thanks for your effort. But it shows normal words as intersection.

Comment: Rectangle1: X=105,Y=660,Width=44,Heigjt=11; Rectangle2: X=107,Y=650, Width=7,Height=11;For Example, How these two rectangles could be intersect? Please explain. Code shows these rectangles as intersected.

Comment: The upper right corner of rect 2 (114, 661) is within the first rectangle with x = 105 .. 149, y = 660 .. 671. It does only by one but it does. You could shrink the rectangles a little bit with `rect.Inflate(-2)`, for example to avoid detecting small overlaps.